# AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'replace' "fasttext"

Tags: python, pandas

Currently I am working on Stack overflow tag predictor using fastText.

I wanted to make my labels as `__label__XX__label__YY` where `XX` and `YY` are tags for a specific row of the dataframe.

```
tags= df['Tags']
```

My `tags` list is:

```
0                 [php]
1             [firefox]
2                   [r]
3                  [c#]
4            [php, api]
...      
179995         [delphi]
179996              [c]
179997        [android]
179998    [java, email]
179999     [linux, php]

Name: Tags, Length: 135552, dtype: object
```

When running the line

```
tags=[s.replace(',' , '__label__') for s in tags]
```

I get an error:

```
AttributeError  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-139-dd4edc84bcad> in <module>
----> 1 tags=[s.replace(' ','__label__') for s in tags]
<ipython-input-139-dd4edc84bcad> in <listcomp>(.0)
----> 1 tags=[s.replace(' ','__label__') for s in tags]

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'replace'
```

I have also posted a screenshot of [my notebook here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/brDIL.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#tags=[s.replace(' ','__label__') for s in tags]
tags =['__label__'.join(s) for s in tags]
```

try this , you should get desired result

Comment: @JacquesGaudin This is actually correct, `join` takes a list as argument

Comment: I want   '__label__' when I encounter ',' 
 
 tags=[s.replace(' ,  ','__label__') for s in tags]

Comment: Its not working...
it give me
sql__label__sql-server',
But I want 
__label__sql__label__sql-server',

Comment: tags =['__label__'+'__label__'.join(s) for s in tags]
this should work for you as per your need